Calculating a percentage in a group_by operation in R
Trying to calculate the %ge of records where a certain ratio is > 1, grouped by another column in R.
I start with the following dataframe:
Scenario (chr), Ratio (fl), OtherCols (chr)

I add a 'pass' column to, which is 1 for a pass, 0 for a fail.
df$pass = with(df, ifelse(Ratio>1,1,0))

Then I'd like to find out the percentage of passes by a given Scenario group, by summing the 'pass' col and dividing by the total number of rows in that group
df_pct <- df %>%
group_by(Scenario) %>%
summarise(pass_pct=sum(pass)/nrow(pass))
df_pct

I'm getting an empty tibble back when printing this though.
Any advice or better way of doing this?
Thanks!

%df_pct is not a valid R identifier.  You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. This post may help.

Use n() instead of nrow(pass)

@AndreWildberg thanks for the suggestion, but this throws an error
Error in summarise():
ℹ In argument: pass_pct = sum(pass)/n(pass).
ℹ In group 1: scenario = abc123.
Caused by error in n():
! unused argument (pass)

@5imon What are you doing exactly? that is the correct answer

ah perfect - thanks @AndreWildberg. If you want to post this as an answer I can accept it?

Use n() to get the desired total number of rows in that group, e.g.
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(pass = ifelse(Ratio>1,1,0)) %>% 
  summarize(pass_pct = sum(pass)/n(), .by = Scenario)

See ?cur_group for other group info functions
